# HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tesseract, tess4j

I am trying to implement OCR using tess4j.When I am running the application in eclipse its working fine.But when I deployed the WAR file to tomcat or Jboss I am getting below error

> HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   The specified module could not be found.
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>
> com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
>     com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
>     com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
>     com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
>     com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:147)
>     com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
>     com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:75)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(TessAPI.java:42)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
>     net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
>     org.infotech.jdol.pdfjs.Utils.doOCRSample(Utils.java:77)
>     org.infotech.jdol.pdfjs.Utils.imageAsPDF(Utils.java:54)
>     org.infotech.jdol.pdfjs.controllers.PdfViewerController.getViewer(PdfViewerController.java:25)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented only for apache that i am posting here

create a folder structure like the below in your apache tomcat.
apache-tomcat-8.0.39\temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64

paste the below dlls in your win32-x86-64 folder

1. gsdll64.dll
2. liblept174.dll
3. libtesseract305.dll

Note: eclipse and java i used are 64 bit

below is the screenshot about the path of dlls that added

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nDsQ.jpg)